# Get maximum of subset of columns with column name in SQLAlchemy

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

Of the 21 cols of my table, I'd like to get the maximum of 20 of those cols for one row:

```
row = session.query(Stats).get(id)
rewards = {}
for c in Stats.__table__.columns:
    if c == 'u_state':
        continue
    rewards[c] = row.getattr(Stats, c)

return max(rewards, key=lambda key: rewards[key])
```

but this results to:

> AttributeError: 'Stats' object has no attribute 'getattr'

What would be the correct way to do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`getattr()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#getattr) is a *function*, not a method on your `Stats` instance. Use it to get specific attribute names from your model instance:

```
row = session.query(Stats).get(id)
rewards = {}
for c in Stats.__table__.columns:
    if c == 'u_state':
        continue
    rewards[c] = getattr(row, c)

return max(rewards, key=lambda key: rewards[key])
```

Note that `c` is a column, not a string, however. It's better to use the [runtime inspection API](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/13/core/inspection.html) here, anyway:

```
for name in inspect(Stats).columns.keys():
    if name == 'u_state':
        continue
    rewards[name] = getattr(row, name)
```